# SQL Server: Understanding log ship utility: sqllogship.exe

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

This is my first time using the stock SQL log shipping setup. The copy operation is failing.

I think I see the issue. I need to change the unc:

```
 '\\Win-2ooc0jplr5k\sql\logbackup\', Backup Destination Directory: 
 '\\10.37.155.187\sql\logs\',
```

I need to change that first unc to an IP, because this environment is not resolving names. (No domain, etc). But when I look at the job, it has this:

```
sqllogship.exe" -Copy 34FCC5A2-8A2C-4581-9A58-04BC60E42DEF -server WIN-2OOC0JPLR5K
```

How do I modify the from/to unc paths?

(I am on SQL 2014, but I believe this topic spans several versions)

Answer (score 2):

In order to change the settings, you don't alter the job directly. Go to the primary database in the log shipping setup in SSMS, right click, choose tasks, then ship transaction logs.

[image: LogShippingProperties]

Click on the button highlighted, which will take you to the following screen:-

[image: CopFileProperties]

This screen will allow you to change the UNC path to an IP address